# Trying to eval(parse(text=function())) to be used in curve()

Tags: r, eval

I created a function that makes the equation used to generated a regression curve in polynomial regression, but I can't make it work on curve()

There's the function itself, which's working fine.

`$

```
Curve.equation=function(x)
{
   coeffs=x$coefficients
   eqq=character()
   for(i in 1:length(coeffs))
   {
      if(i==1){eqq[i]=coeffs[i]}
      if(grepl("\\^",names(coeffs[i])))
      {
         num=grep("\\^",unlist(strsplit(names(coeffs[i]),"")))+1
         eqq[i]=ifelse(substring(coeffs[i],1,1)=="-",paste0(coeffs[i],"*x^",substring(names(coeffs)[i],num,num)),paste0("+",coeffs[i],"*x^",substring(names(coeffs)[i],num,num)))
      }
      if(!grepl("\\^",names(coeffs[i]))&i>1)
      {
         eqq[i]=ifelse(substring(coeffs[i],1,1)=="-",paste0(coeffs[i],"*x"),paste0("+",coeffs[i],"*x"))
      }
   }
   paste(eqq,collapse="")
}`
```

Simulated data

```
`$
fn=function(x)15+2.5*x+2*x^2+x^3+50*rnorm(length(x),100,100)
a=rnorm(200,30,3)
b=fn(a)
plot(b~a)
lmab=lm(b~a+I(a^2)+I(a^3))
```

`

... and here's where I have a problem.
I tried to

`$ curve(Curve.equation(lmab),add=TRUE,col="blue")`

also

`$ curve(eval(parse(text=Curve.equation(lmab))),add=TRUE,col="blue")`

, but both lines returns me 
'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'

Comment: It doesn't appear that function returns an R function. Looks to return a character value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That returned an R character vector of length 1:

```
Curve.equation(lmab)
[1] "-26488.6153547735+4928.74310702739*x-217.568666179266*x^2+4.00331698261622*x^3"
```

This will allow you to take that character value and place it into a "blank" function object. There is no need for `eval`, since `parse` returns the necessary expression. It performs a test whether it's possible to build a valid R expression tree from that character value:

```
func <- function(x){}
    body(func) <- parse(text=Curve.equation(lmab))


> func
function (x) 
-26488.6153547735 + 4928.74310702739 * x - 217.568666179266 * 
    x^2 + 4.00331698261622 * x^3
```

Since func is now a function with a single formal parameter named "x", the `curve`-function is happy:

```
png(); curve(func, -10,10); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice. Thank you very much!